# Return an array while telling him the length of this array?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to filter an strings array passed in, something like this:

```
char **
filter_vids(char **vids, size_t n) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char ** filted = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        filted[i] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(some_filter(vids[i])) {
            strcpy(filted[count++], vids[i]);
            printf("in filter:%s\n", vids[i]);
        }
    }
    return filted;
}
```

But the caller may not known the length of return array, it's extractly the `counter` variable, so what's the best practice of returning an array while telling him the right length of array?
such as

```
char **
filter_vids(char **vids, size_t n, int *output_length)
```

It's the best practice of using `output_length`?

I edit this function to this, as your suggestions:

    `char **
    filter_vids(char **vids, size_t n) {
       int i;
       int count = 0;
       char ** filted = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char *));
       for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(vids[i][0] <= 'f') {
                filted[count++] = strdup(vids[i]);
            }
        }
        filted[count] = NULL;
        return filted;
    }`

Comment: I would do like that ... if someone threatened me to code such things in pure C.

Comment: If one  takes `size_t` in, I'd give `size_t` out!

Comment: Also, you're leaking memory and what not. You should only `malloc` whenever you're setting a new string; or perhaps even use `strdup`.

Comment: @Antii There's nothing wrong *per se* with allocating memory in a function, although it should be documented and should probably be avoided as a matter of style (because it is not obvious who is the owner of the new memory). Also this function does not leak: The original array of strings `vids` which was passed as an argument is not altered and will still be available to the caller for deallocation, if necessary.

Comment: @moooeeeep input is n，output will be less or equal n

Answer (score 1):

To pass a pointer to an integer length variable whose value is then set in the function is certainly a good way. As Malcolm said, it is also general and can be used for  sets of values which do not have an "invalid" member.

In the case of pointers with their invalid null pointer value one can mark the end of valid entries with a null pointer. For example, the array of string pointers which the C run time uses to pass command line arguments to `main` is thus terminated.

Which method to choose depends a little on how the caller wants to use the resulting array. If it is processed sequentially, a `(while *p){ ..; ++p; }` feels idiomatic. If, on the other hand, you need random access and must perform the equivalent of a `strlen` before you can do anything with the array, then it is probably better to return the length via a pointed-to length variable right away.

Two remarks:

First, note the difference between

- a valid pointer to an empty string (if somebody called, let's say, `myProg par1 "" par2`, `argv[2]` could be a valid pointer to a zero byte);
- and a null pointer which is pointing nowhere; in the example, `argv[4]` would be the null pointer, indicating the end of the argument list.

Second, You `malloc` more memory than you need which is wasteful in the case of longer strings and/or strict filters. You could instead allocate the string on demand inside the `if` clause.

Comment: You'll also see the variable method as suggested by the OP. That's necessary for non-pointer arrays or pointer arrays where nulls are valid.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Yes, of course. It's just that you need another variable making the interface less elegant. But "canonical" was an exaggeration. If this occurs more than twice in my program I'd be writing an array struct with a `data`,and `length` element as well as an allocator and de-allocator ;-).

Comment: If the length passed in is `n`, and I filter nothing, then I need to alloc `n+1` strings,  in order to append a extra `NULL` pointer?

Comment: @user1337896 Yes, correct. That's how `argv`  does it.

Answer (score 1):

These are common options:

1. Receive the allowed size as parameter by pointer, overwrite it with the actual size, return the array as return value.
2. Receive the output array as parameter by pointer, update as required, return the actual size as return value.
3. Append a sentinel value to the output array (here a null pointer), as suggested in the other answer.
4. Use a more sophisticated data structure as a return value. You could use a struct, which stores the size alongside the array or a linked list.

Example (untested):

```
typedef char* mystring;
typedef mystring* mystringarray;
typedef struct { mystringarray *arr; size_t size } mysizedstringarray;

/* returns filtered array, size will be updated to reflect the valid size */
mystringarray* myfun1(mystringarray in, size_t* size);

/* out will be allocated and populated, actual size is returned */
size_t myfun2(mystringarray in, size_t size, mystringarray* out);

/* output array contains valid items until sentinel value (NULL) is reached */
mystringarray* myfun3(mystringarray in, size_t size);

/* returns filtered array with actual size */
mysizedstringarray myfun4(mystringarray in, size_t size);
```